# Bootstrap 4 navbar using more than 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my bootstrap 4 navbar.

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <container class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#top">MOEINICH</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
    <container class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </container>
  </container>
</nav>
```

and the css:
https://pastebin.com/2D5HVmVy (for some reason, I couldnt paste it into the code tags)

Comment: "I have a problem with my bootstrap 4 navbar." I think you can be more precise, explain your problem and what you expect. "for some reason, I couldnt paste it into the code tags" you need an empty line before the code, and more text, stack overflow does not accept code only questions.

Comment: Your `<container>` tags should be `<div>` tags